How do I quantify the significance of a percentage ranked data set?
I'm considering seven different forecast models for a given data set, over a number of forecast iterations, and quantifying the number of times each forecast model was the most accurate overall.
I need some way to quantify the significance of the results. For example, if a given forecast model ranked #1 out of 7 23% of the time (with an equal distribution among 7 forecasts being 14.2%) how significant is that?
I would like to be able to establish some kind of baseline for significance among these results. I suspect this may involve some kind of normal distribution, but I don't know how to calculate that. Since I'm always working with percentages and I'm always considering 7 forecasts, a single reference table would be ideal — if I could point to 23% being highly significant, but 18% being somewhat significant or something like that.
On their own, these percentages lack sufficient context.

What do you suppose significance provides you for this particular task? Suppose you said it was significant. Then what?

@DemetriPananos: If it's significant, it supports the hypothesis. It's a scientific study. Significance matters. Without a measure of significance, the results are just numbers.
